# Rxjs: conditional delay in concatMap

Tags: angular, rxjs

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

I want to show a message (and fire animation on its container) on my page immediately unless the previous message has been fired less than 8 seconds ago.
In that case, wait the 8 seconds to pass and fire the second observable.

I think I have to use `concatMap` and `delay` operators, but I'm struggling to find the right combination.

This is the closest try I got:

```js
    this.message$ = this.messageService.message.pipe(
      concatMap((msg) => {
        return of(msg).pipe(
          tap(() => {
            const messageTween = gsap.fromTo(
              "#message",
              { opacity: 0 },
              { opacity: 1, duration: "0.5" }
            );
            messageTween.reverse().delay(5);
          }),
          delay(8000)
        );
      })
    );
```

Here I get the right graphical effect, but the value of `message` is updated after 8 seconds.

Can you help me?

Comment: I don't understand what doesn't work. `message` is updated after 8s so that's good or bad?

Comment: it is bad. I want the message to be updated immediately if 8 seconds from the last are already passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `delay` an `EMPTY` observable to create an observable that waits for a certain duration and then completes. Merge that with another observable to compose an observable that has a minimum run-time before completion.

Here's how that might look:

```js
// Helper Function
const gsapMakeOpaque = _ => gsap.fromTo(
  "#message",
  { opacity: 0 },
  { opacity: 1, duration: "0.5" }
).reverse().delay(5);

// Solution
this.message$ = this.messageService.message.pipe(
  concatMap(msg => merge(
    of(msg).pipe(tap(gsapMakeOpaque)),
    EMPTY.pipe(delay(8000))
  ))
);
```

Since your first observable is just a singleton that you already have the value for, you can simplify this a little bit further. Create an observable that completes after 8 seconds and have it `startWith` your singleton value.

That might look like this:

```js
this.message$ = this.messageService.message.pipe(
  concatMap(msg => EMPTY.pipe(
    delay(8000),
    startWith(msg),
    tap(gsapMakeOpaque)
  ))
);
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect and very coincise!

Answer (score 3):

You're almost there.

1. The `delay` must be above the `tap` operator that triggers the animation. Note that the order of piped operators affects the chain of modified observables.
2. You could use the [`timestamp`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/timestamp) operator to enforce the delay only if the current emission is within 8 seconds.

```js
this.message$ = this.messageService.message.pipe(
  timestamp(),
  concatMap(({timestamp, value}) =>
    Date.now() - timestamp < 8000 ? of(value) : of(value).pipe(delay(8000));
  ),
  tap(() => {
    const messageTween = gsap.fromTo(
      "#message",
      { opacity: 0 },
      { opacity: 1, duration: "0.5" }
    );
    messageTween.reverse().delay(5);
  })
);
```

But there might be an intrinsic error in your logic. Say 5 seconds has elapsed since the first emission. Since the induced delay is compared to current timestamp instead of previous emission's timestamp, the second emission would be delayed a total of 13 seconds. To solve this, you could cache the timestamp of the previous emission is a variable and compare the current emission's timestamp against it instead of `Date.now()`.